# Problems with posting Paypal values

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

It is assumed that using the form, variables are passed by post method to return page, but it is not doing that, and I don't know what I can do about it, since transit through the Paypal website is out of my control.

Any idea?

This is my button. I have the same situation with another one.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="name@dom.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Algo">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="8.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_GET['sub'];?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.web.com/ok.php"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.web.com/ko.php"> 

  <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/img/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variables by setting them as url parameters in the return page. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.web.com/ok.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>&custom=<?php echo $_GET['sub'];?>">
```